# Passing data in AS3 to a Query String (API)

Tags: actionscript-3, query-string, flash-cs6

I'm writing a mobile app where a user can match ingredients to recipes. I have stumbled across http://www.recipepuppy.com/about/api/ which provides a very simple API to search by comma separated ingredients such as:

```
http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=onions,garlic&format=xml
```

I have various ingredients stored in a shared object like so:

```
so.data.meat1 = "beef"
so.data.meat2 = "chicken"
so.data.meat3 = "lamb"
so.data.veg1 = "green beans"
etc etc..
```

I am completely new to AS3, so I don't really have an idea of the main methods / classes that could achieve this.

So
 1. How can I pass my shared object's data into the query string of recipe puppy's url above?
 2. How would I load the XML results into a datagrid or similiar component?

edit: this is what I have got so far:

```
var url : String = 'http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/';

            // url variables all which will appear after ? sign
            var urlVariables : URLVariables = new URLVariables ();
                urlVariables['i'] = so.data.meat1;
                urlVariables['i'] = so.data.meat2;
                urlVariables['format'] = "xml";
                // here you can add as much as you need

            // creating new URL Request
            // setting the url
            var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest  ( url );
                // setting the variables it need to cary
                request.data = urlVariables;
                // setting method of delivering variables ( POST or GET )
                request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

            // creating actual loader
            var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
                loader.load ( request );
                trace(request.data);
```

It's working well, but my current setup of the urlVariables['i'] only allows me to specify one 'i' variable, how do I specify multiple variable values for the 'i' variable?

Comment: `urlVariables['i'] = so.data.meat1+","+so.data.meat2` or keep ingredients in an array like so: `var ingredients:Array = [so.data.meat1,so.data.meat2];` then use join like so: `urlVariables['i'] = ingredients.join();`

Comment: Thank you that looks about right, can you post it as answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for an answer I need to enhance it:)

first you should store ingredients as an array in SO, like shown here [SharedObject#data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#data)

```
so.data.ingredients = ["beef","chicken","lamb"];
```

then you can pass it to the urlVariables as:

```
urlVariables['i'] = so.data.ingredients.join();
```

of course I would add som tests if the so.data.ingredients exists to acoid any errors thrown,